# Lipschitz condition for complex measures on the circle group

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $\mu$ be a complex, regular, Borel measure on the circle group $\mathbb{T}$. Define its distribution function $F_\mu : [0, 2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $F_\mu(x)=\mu([0,x))$ if $x \in (0, 2\pi)$ and $F_\mu(0)=\mu(\{0\})$. Say $F_\mu$ satisfies Lipschitz condition of order $\alpha>0$ iff there is some $C \geq 0 $ such that for any $x, y \in [0, 2\pi)$,

$|F_\mu(x) - F_\mu(y)| \leq C |x - y| ^\alpha$

How do I show that this implies that there is some $K \geq 0 $ such that for any interval $I \subseteq [0, 2\pi)$ of length $h$, $|\mu(I)| \leq K h^\alpha$ ?

I've noted that if I let the endpoints of such an itnerval $I$ be $x < y$ I have that

$|F_\mu(x) - F_\mu(y)| = |\mu([x,y))|$

From an article I am reading it appears that $\mu(\{z\})=0$ for any $z$. I thought about using the Lipschitz condition for $F_\mu$ to go about this, and I saw that

$|\mu([z,z+\varepsilon))| \leq C \varepsilon^\alpha$

But how would I compare $|\mu(\{z\})|$ and $|\mu([z,z+\varepsilon))|$, since $\mu$ is a complex measure?

**~~~EDIT~~~**

solution (to a corrected version of the question) is in comments below

Comment: If $\mu$ is the Dirac measure at $0$, then $F$ is constant but the result is not valid. It is valid, however, intervals with left-boundary strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @LuizCordeiro . That is an interesting point. I had made a comment but I realized I might be wrong, just thinking...

Comment: In your comment @LuizCordeiro are you saying you understand the implication above if we take only intervals with left endpoint strictly greater than $0$? If that is the case, would you be able to provide some insight?

Comment: If $x>0$, then $\mu[0,x)=F(x)=\lim F(x+1/n)=\lim\mu[0,x+1/n)=\mu[0,x]=\mu[0,x)+\mu\{x\}$, so $\mu\{x\}=0$. Now simply use $F(y)-F(x)=\mu[x,y)$ for $x<y$, which you have already obtained, and add or remove the endpoints as necessary, since this does not change the measure.

Comment: Thank you @LuizCordeiro . That is very nice. But there is one detail I do not understand if I could bother you a little more. Why is it that $\lim \mu ([0,x+1/n)) = \mu ([0,x])$ ? I was able to see the first limit $\lim \mu ([0,x+1/n)) = \mu ([0,x))$ using the Lipschitz condition of order $\alpha$ for $\mu$, namely that $|\mu ([x,x+1/n))| \leq C (1/n)^\alpha$. However if I try to repeat this argument, I get $\mu ([0,x+1/n) - \mu ([0,x]) = \mu ((x,x+1/n))$, and so a $(,)$ interval instead of a $[,)$ interval. If $\mu$ was a real measure I'd use monotonicity, but $\mu$ is a complex measure...

Comment: The limit $\lim\mu[0,x+1/n)=\mu[0,x]$ is usual measure theory: If $\mu$ is a finite measure and $A_n$ is a decreasing sequence of sets, then $\mu(\bigcap A_n)=\lim_n\mu(A_n)$. We use this with $A_n=[0,x+1/n)$, in which case $\bigcap A_n=[0,x]$.

Comment: Ah! I should have seen that. Thank you @LuizCordeiro , you have been very helpful.